# Netcat pipe , redirect out put of cmd to other telented machine

Tags: windows, cmd, netcat

I have got a windows machine and a netcat, basically what i did is, I got into the command line and ran : `nc -vv -l -p 1234 | cmd` so every connection that comes in every thing that the user writes it pipes it into cmd, thing is the other telneted machine cannot see the output of cmd for some reason, does anybody know an answer to that? , maybe i need to make the cmd output as a stdin. idk

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't quite clear to me.

Do you want to send the *output* of a command to a new instance?

```
ping localhost | cmd
```

(Note: this will give you syntax errors - just to show the prinicple)

Or do you want to send the *command* itself to a new instance?

```
echo ping localhost | cmd
```